# Retaining empty strings when using POLYBASE to copy data from Azure SQL db to Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, polybase

I am copying data from an Azure SQL database into Azure Synapse using the Copy Data activity. I am attempting to use Polybase as the copy method. This works successfully on most tables but I have a source and destination table with the following columns:

```
Fee DECIMAL(18,2) NULL,
FeeReason VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
```

For reasons beyond my control, I am unable to change the columns to allow NULLs in the FeeReason column. In the table, if Fee is NULL, then FeeReason is an empty string.

When I try and copy the table from Azure SQL DB into Synapse I get an error for the Fee column when that value is NULL:

```
ErrorCode=FailedDbOperation, ......HadoopSqlException: Error converting data type VARCHAR to DECIMAL.....Detailed Message=Empty string can't be converted to DECIMAL.....
```

and the solution to this problem is to set the "Use Type Default" setting to false as per  [loading-to-decimal-column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse#loading-to-decimal-column)

However, making this change results in the FeeReason value to be NULL in Synapse when the value is an empty string in the source (Azure DB). Is there anyway I can set "Use Type Default" set to False for decimal columns only?

I have a terribly dirty solution to this which involves creating a BIT column in the source database called FeeReasonIsEmpty and flag records where the FeeReason is actually an empty string and once the data has been copied over, I can just update the NULL values to empty strings where relevant. I want to avoid this if possibly because in reality I have multiple tables with multiple decimal columns and multiple varchar/nvarchar columns with empty strings that need to be retained. This dirty solution would mean I'd need to create an "IsEmpty" column for each of those and I don't really want to do that.
Thank-you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Unfortunately, we cannot control `UseTypeDefault` setting to only specific columns at this moment.*

To avoid your issue, at this moment you must go with the option of bit column in the source dataset. As far I tried to find solutions and till now that’s the only options seem to create `IsEmpty` columns for respective columns.

***Note: Currently, PolyBase in ADF accepts only the same number of columns as in the target table: [Columns with default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse#columns-with-default-values)***

I would encourage you to add this case as feedback item on below link. Product team will closely monitor feed backs there and consider them for future releases: [***FeedBack***](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory)